# Where should I ask questions about cell phones (problems with hardware, software, et cetera)?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where should I ask questions about cell phones? Is there a Stack Exchange site about that?

For example, I have this question: *All of a sudden I have no sound with my HTC One S (running Android 4.1.1). How come? How to solve it?*

**EDIT**
Okay, forget the recommendations. But my question still counts for the why and how questions.
Second, the abovementioned question does not seem to be Android-specific. So I doubt whether the question should be migrated to that site.

Comment: [android.se]. [apple.se]. [windowsphone.se] is in beta. No site for Blackberry or for feature phones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [Stack Exchange site for Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/about), where these questions may be on topic:

> - Using your Android device
> - Using a particular app on your Android device
> - Trying to solve an error or other issue with Android
> - Real problems or questions that you’ve encountered

Keep in mind you'll still need to perform your due diligence of research and the necessary/appropriate context to allow your question to be answered.

Comment: The example question wouldn't be on topic for Android, by the looks of it.

Comment: Even if he provided enough details for how to diagnose, logcat etc?? That sucks.

Comment: The current example question is spot-on for [android.se]. It's not specific to the OS, sure, but the device doesn't run anything else. We have handled similar questions.